# Windows command prompt not launching on executing batch file TFS (after build event)

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-2013, tfs

I am integrating my automated robot framework selenium test with TFS server. Where on any changes on TFS build, should trigger these suite.

I have created sample script and batch file to execute this scripts(test.bat). Batch working fine manually.

Now I have integrated this with TFS using Invoke process entity with the help of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551.aspx#code_proj_references.

I observed that batch file is executed as soon as code change reflected in TFS, but console is not displayed. So my log files shows required browser is not opened to execute tests..

Robot test suite:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***

login

    Open Browser    http://www.facebook.com    gc
    Input Text    email    xxxx
    Input Text    pass    xxxx
    Click Element    loginbutton
```

The batch file:

```
echo hello
D:
cd D:\GURU_Testing\Facebook_Login
start pybot D:\GURU_Testing\Facebook_Login
```

The error message:

```
Keyword 'Capture Page Screenshot' could not be run on failure: No browser is open
```

So test is running but it is failed because windows prompt and browser is not launching.

I am using TFS 2013 server.

Any help on this highly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The build agent is running in [Session 0](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2007/04/27/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation.aspx) and you will never be able to interact with the desktop.

You have two options:

1. Configure the Build Agent to [run interactively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181712.aspx#interactive) or
2. use a Test Agent again [configured to run interactively](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee291332.aspx)

If you have a small team and control your build infrastructure, the first option is quick and simple. The second option allows you more complex configuration and may run on multi-server QA environment.